# Optimization and construction of a red-black tree if the comparator of the key is not overridden

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, comparable, red-black-tree

How is the optimization and construction of a red-black tree inside the HashMap Bucket if the comparator of the key is not overridden?

Here is what I found on the subject:

HashMap can contain keys of different classes.
And some of them may be comparable and some of them not.

This means that key mix is pretty straightforward: first, all keys from first class goes, and then all from the second.

```
    /**
     * Tie-breaking utility for ordering insertions when equal
     * hashCodes and non-comparable. We don't require a total
     * order, just a consistent insertion rule to maintain
     * equivalence across rebalancings. Tie-breaking further than
     * necessary simplifies testing a bit.
     */
    static int tieBreakOrder(Object a, Object b) {
        int d;
        if (a == null || b == null ||
            (d = a.getClass().getName().
             compareTo(b.getClass().getName())) == 0)
            d = (System.identityHashCode(a) <= System.identityHashCode(b) ?
                 -1 : 1);
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.